# How Create Multiple array from a array?

Tags: php

I have an array in the same level.

```
$original = Array(
        0=>"03ssss",//substr("03ssss",0,2)="03" => parent index

          1=>"04aaaa",
          2=>"05absd",
          3=>"07sdsa",
          4=>"08sdsd",

        5=>"03tttt", //substr("03tttt",0,2)="03" => parent index

          6=>"04xxxx, //substr("03xxxx",0,2)="04" => child index
            7=>"05sdds",
            8=>"07sdfd",
            9=>"08sdff",
          10=>"04xsax", //substr("03xxxx",0,2)="04" => child index
            11=>"05sdfs",
            12=>"07sdfds",
            13=>"08asap",
    )
```

How Can create from `$original` to multiple array something like this?

```
$move_level = Array(
 0=>array(0=>"04aaaa 05absd 07sdsa 08sdsd"),
 1=>array(0=>"04xxxx 05sdds 07sdfd 08sdff", 
          1=>"04xsax 05sdfs 07sdfds 08asap") 
);
```

thanks

Comment: Your `$move_level` example doesn't make sense. you want to copy the same 4 elements from `$original` into multiple separate arrays in the new array?

Comment: What are the rules for creating the new array? Are you simply dropping any element with a leading '03' and then chunking the remaining elements into blocks of four?

Comment: It's not totally clear what your example means, especially due to the duplicate elements in the original array.

Comment: @Matchu Not duplicate ,the input are difference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This splits the $original array into sub arrays at each element starting with '03':

```
$move_level = array();
$ary = array();
foreach($original as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, '03') === 0) {
        $move_level[] = $ary;
        $ary = array();
    } else {
        $ary[] = $value;
    }
}
$move_level[] = $ary;
```

Comment: @user576875 I need join "04xxxx 05xxxx 07xxxx 08xxxx" join this together Like my example output.But It differences from yours.Do you have any idea.?