# How Create multiple array from an array and concatenate each elments?

Tags: php

How Create multiple array from an array and concatenate each elments?

I have an array in the same level.

```
$original = Array(
        0=>"03ssss",//first "03"

          1=>"04aaaa",//first "04" of the first "03"
          2=>"05absd",
          3=>"07sdsa",
          4=>"08sdsd",

        5=>"03tttt", //second "03"

          6=>"04xxxx, //first "04" of the second "03"
            7=>"05sdds",
            8=>"07sdfd",
            9=>"08sdff",
          10=>"04xsax", //second "04" of second "03"
            11=>"05sdfs",
            12=>"07sdfds",
            13=>"08asap",
    )
```

base on `$original`

`if(substr("03ssss",0,2)="03")` Will be came the index of main array

`else` will the index of child array and`concat` with these elements with if we found `substr("03ssss",0,2)="04"`

So the expected `result` look like:

```
$move_level = Array(
 0=>array( // first "03" 
    0=>"04aaaa 05absd 07sdsa 08sdsd"),//first 04 of the first "03"
 1=>array(// second "03"
         0=>"04xxxx 05sdds 07sdfd 08sdff",  // Concat with "04"
         1=>"04xsax 05sdfs 07sdfds 08asap" // Concat with "04"
         )
);
```

If I try:

```
$move_level = array(); //main array
$ary = array(); // sub array
foreach($original as $value) {
    if (substr($value,0,2) =="03") {
        $move_level[] = $ary;// create main array
        $ary = array();// create sub 
    } else { // to to join all element with "04"
        $ary[] = ($value);
    }

}

$move_level[] = $ary;


echo '<pre>';
print_r($move_level);
echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04xxxx
        [1] => 05xxxx
        [2] => 07xxxx
        [3] => 08xxxx
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04xxxx
        [1] => 05xxxx
        [2] => 07xxxx
        [3] => 08xxxx
        [4] => 04xxxx
        [5] => 05xxxx
        [6] => 07xxxx
        [7] => 08xxxx
    )

 )
```

I WANT GET :

Array
    (

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04xxxx 05xxxx 07xxxx 08xxxx
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04xxxx 05xxxx 07xxxx 08xxxx,
        [1]=>04xxxx 05xxxx 07xxxx 08xxxx
    )

 )
```

How Can create from `$original` to multiple array something like this?
thanks

Comment: The English in this question is really unclear. Can you elaborate on what the output would be based on what conditions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Create Multiple array from a array ? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807625/how-create-multiple-array-from-a-array)

Comment: first,sorry with bad english. I have updated the question,Hope it more clear,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$original = array(  0   => "03ssss",    //first "03"
                    1   => "04aaaa",    //first "04" of the first "03"
                    2   => "05absd",
                    3   => "07sdsa",
                    4   => "08sdsd",
                    5   => "03tttt",    //second "03"
                    6   => "04xxxx",    //first "04" of the second "03"
                    7   => "05sdds",
                    8   => "07sdfd",
                    9   => "08sdff",
                    10  => "04xsax",    //second "04" of second "03"
                    11  => "05sdfs",
                    12  => "07sdfds",
                    13  => "08asap",
                );

$r = -1;
$move_level = array();
foreach($original as $value) {
    if(substr($value,0,2) == "03") {
        ++$r;
        $j = 0;
        $move_level[$r][$j] = '';
    } else {
        if (($j % 4) > 0) $value = ' '.$value;
        $move_level[$r][floor($j / 4)] .= $value;
        ++$j;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($move_level);
echo '</pre>';
```