# DO customize PHP Array?

Tags: php

```
$original  = Array(
0=>"03A ",//first "03", substr("04w",0,2)=="03"
1=>"04a ",//first "04" of first "03"
2=>"05b ",
3=>"06c ",
4=>"07d ",

6=>"04w ",//second "04" of first "03"
7=>"05x ",
8=>"06y ",
9=>"07z ",

10=>"03B    ",//second "03"
11=>"04l    ",//first "04" of second "03" //substr("04w",0,2)=="03"
12=>"05m    ",
13=>"06n    ",
14=>"07o    ",

15=>"04l    ",//second "04" of second "03" //substr("04l",0,2)=="03"
16=>"05m    ",
17=>"06n    ",
18=>"07o    "
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($original);
echo '</pre>';

function customize_array($original){
  $customized_array = array();
  foreach($original as $value) {
      if(substr($value,0,2) == "03") {
      // CHANGE 1
      $save = $value;// saved "03" yo put in child too.
      ++$r;//inc parent
      $j = 0; // child 
      $customized_array[$r][$j] =$value; // create parent
      } else {
      if (($j % 4) > 0) $value .= $value;
      // CHANGE 2
      else if ($j && $j % 4 == 0) $value = $save.$value;
      $customized_array[$r][floor($j / 4)] .= $value;
      ++$j;//inc child
      }
  }
  return $customized_array;
}

$display_list = customize_array($original);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($display_list);
echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
/*

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03A  04a 05b 05b 06c 06c 07d 07d 
            [1] => 03A  04w 05x 05x 06y 06y 07z 07z 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03B  04l 05m 05m 06n 06n 07o 07o 
            [1] => 03B  04l 05m 05m 06n 06n 07o 07o 
        )

)
```

*/

Everybody here have any idea with the function to get the this result.

```
/*

   Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03A  04a 05b 06c 07d 
            [1] => 03A  04w 05x 06y 07z 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03B  04l 05m 06n 07o 
            [1] => 03B  04l 05m 06n     07o 
        )

)


*/
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814431/how-create-multiple-array-from-an-array-and-concatenate-each-elments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807625/how-create-multiple-array-from-a-array

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this just a repost of your question from the other day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes:

```
foreach($original as $value) {
    if(substr($value,0,2) == "03") {
        // CHANGE 1
        $save = $value;
        ++$r;//inc parent
        $j = 0; // child 
        $move_level[$r][$j] =$value;
    } else {
        if (($j % 4) > 0) $value .= $value;
        // CHANGE 2
        else if ($j && $j % 4 == 0) $value = $save.$value;
        $move_level[$r][floor($j / 4)] .= $value;
        ++$j;//inc child
    }
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/4Nynl)

Comment: Thanks that you understand my questions and give me a good answers.100% agree

Comment: Why it still got the duplicate element ?Did you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with array_slice and implode:

```
$a1 = array_slice($original, 0, 5);
$a2 = array_slice($original, 5, 4);
$a3 = array_slice($original, 10, 5);
$a4 = array_slice($original, 15, 4);

$output = new Array(
  new Array(implode("",$a1), implode("",$a2)), 
  new Array(implode("",$a3), implode("",$a4))
);
```

You should be able to use similar code to this in your for-loop if you want to do it for a dynamic array

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is trim the first 3 characters like `substr($val, 3);` and past the 03a before it.. 
or do you wanna get the first 3 characters from array index 0 and past/replace it in index 1??
if thats the case do like:

```
$array[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03A04a05b05b06c06c07d07d //yes "03A" here 
        [1] => 04w05x05x06y06y07z07z // no "03A" here 
    )

$array[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03B04l05m05m06n06n07o07o //"03B" here 
        [1] => 04l05m05m06n06n07o07o // no "03B" here 
    )
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
   $first = substr($value[0], 0, 3);
   $new_array[] = array($value[0], $value[1]);
}

print_r($new_array);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03A04a05b05b06c06c07d07d //yes "03A" here 
        [1] => 03A04w05x05x06y06y07z07z //yes "03A" here 
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03B04l05m05m06n06n07o07o //"03B" here 
        [1] => 03B04l05m05m06n06n07o07o//"03B" here 
    )

)
```

Im sure there is a better way, this is a global way i think